# SQL union all error while using DATE_FORMATE in node

Tags: mysql, sql

in the bellow query I am receiving the date as '2022-09-06T18:30:00.000Z' I want it as YYYY_MM_DD

```
      let sql_of_prime =  ` 
((SELECT id , collection_date, collection_type 
FROM bank_book 
WHERE ledger_num = 'vr15' ) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT id , collection_date, collection_type 
FROM cash_book 
WHERE ledger_num = 'vr15' )) 
ORDER BY collection_date ASC ;`
```

soo that's why i used `DATE_FORMAT` and now its not working

```
      let sql_of_prime =  ` 
((SELECT id , DATE_FORMAT(collection_date, "%Y-%m-%d") , collection_type 
FROM bank_book 
WHERE ledger_num = 'vr15' ) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT id , DATE_FORMAT(collection_date, "%Y-%m-%d") , collection_type 
FROM cash_book 
WHERE ledger_num = 'vr15' )) 
ORDER BY collection_date ASC ;`
```

the first query is working but the below one is not
I have no idea why can any one suggest a solution

console log

````
Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'collection_date' in 'order clause'
sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'collection_date' in 'order clause'",
```
````

Comment: `and now its not working` ... _what_ is not working?

Comment: i have added the console logs also it shows ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR

Comment: I guess you're using a JavaScript library that converts date columns to native `Date` objects. It probably makes more sense to format the result in your application, or disable the behaviour in the library (if there's a setting for that) than to mess with the query.

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT(collection_date, "%Y-%m-%d")` can be replaced with more simple `DATE(collection_date)`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no alias `collection_date` available, as the first subquery in the union does not select it.  Use this version:

```sql
(SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(collection_date, '%Y_%m_%d') AS dt, collection_type
 FROM bank_book
 WHERE ledger_num = 'vr15') 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT id, DATE_FORMAT(collection_date, '%Y_%m_%d'), collection_type
 FROM cash_book 
 WHERE ledger_num = 'vr15')
ORDER BY dt;
```

Comment: This may result in incorrect output ordering because the rows with the same date will be sorted indefenitely within the same date whereas in original query they're sorted according to complete datetime value.

Answer (score 0):

To produce the output with strictly the same rows ordering you must use

```sql
SELECT id, collection_date, collection_type 
FROM ( SELECT id, 
              collection_date AS collection_datetime, 
              DATE_FORMAT(collection_date, "%Y-%m-%d") AS collection_date, 
              collection_type 
       FROM bank_book 
       WHERE ledger_num = 'vr15' 
       UNION ALL 
       SELECT id, 
              collection_date, 
              DATE_FORMAT(collection_date, "%Y-%m-%d"), 
              collection_type 
       FROM cash_book 
       WHERE ledger_num = 'vr15' 
     ) AS combined_rowset
ORDER BY collection_datetime ASC
```